# SMTP No Suitable Auth

Tags: python, email, authentication, smtp, office365

I wrote an email script, and I have gotten my company to allow my IP address access to the SMTP Relay server
But I get this error:

SMTPException: No suitable authentication method found.

```
context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
server = smtplib.SMTP('server###.nyc.org',587) #server### is replaced by actual string
server.connect("server###.nyc.org",587)
server.ehlo() # Can be omitted
server.starttls(context=context) # Secure the connection
server.ehlo() # Can be omitted
server.login(sender_email, password)


server.sendmail(
sender_email,rcpt, message.as_string())
```

Non of the methods I search for help, I have tries SMTP_SSL, ssl.create_default_context(), changing ehlo to helo, and switching ports.

Comment: Per [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.auth), you need to find out what authentication method the server is using.  If it isn't supported by smtplib directly you'll need to find a third-party package that implements it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove the log in. This maybe related to the fact that I am connected to a relay server, where my IP address was added to a list to allow connection there

```
context = ssl._create_unverified_context(protocol= ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
server = smtplib.SMTP('server###.nyc.org',587)
server.connect("server###.nyc.org",)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls(context=context)
server.ehlo()
server.sendmail(
sender_email,rcpt, message.as_string())
```